# AlertView Display in Lock Screen?

Tags: ios, uialertview

If I set an alertview for push notification handling, how it will look like in lock screen?

Is it like this one?

[image]

And also for the title, is it from apps name? Can't i change it dynamically?

Sorry I can't test it by myself since still on brainstorming and design process..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will look exactly like this one although it can change.
Users can choose the style of alerts they want: Banners, Alerts or None.

And for the title, yes, it is the application's name itself. You can't change it.

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: Thanks for your both answers :)

Answer (score 2):

How it will look depends on the user's device settings. You can find it under

Settings -> Notifications -> Your app -> Alert style

Comment: Thanks for your both answers :)